# How would you loop this in R?

Tags: r

I have this kinda simple task I'm having hard time looping.

So, lets assume I have this tibble:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tibble(player1 = c("aa","bb","cc"), player2 = c("cc","aa","bb"))
```

My goal here, is to make three new columns ( for each unique "player" I have) and assign value of 1 to the column, if the player is "player1", -1 if the player is "player2" and 0 otherwise.

Previously, I have been doing it like this:

```
dat %>% mutate( aa = ifelse(player1 == "aa",1,ifelse(player2 == "aa",-1,0)),
          bb = ifelse(player1 == "bb",1,ifelse(player2 == "bb",-1,0)),
          cc = ifelse(player1 == "cc",1,ifelse(player2 == "cc",-1,0)))
```

This works, but now I have hundreds of different "players", so it would seem silly to do this manually like that. I have tried and read about loops in R, but I just can't get this one right.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, how can you have "hundreds of different players" but still having only 3 options (1 ; 0 and -1). Do you mean to make this case more general for any name given to "player1" and "player2"?

Answer (score 5):

Using `model.matrix()` from base R:

```
dat[unique(dat$player1)] <- 
  model.matrix(~0+ player1, data = dat) - model.matrix(~0+ player2, data = dat)

dat
  player1 player2    aa    bb    cc
  <chr>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 aa      cc          1     0    -1
2 bb      aa         -1     1     0
3 cc      bb          0    -1     1
```

This assumes you have all players in both columns. Otherwise you would need to convert them to factors with the appropriate levels and replace `unique` with `levels`.

Answer (score 2):

We could go from initial structure to "long"(-er) format, with one row per (game, player), recode to 1/-1, and then go wide again with the desired output:

```
dat %>% 
  mutate(game_id = row_number()) %>% 
  gather("role", "player", -game_id) %>% 
  mutate(role = recode(role, "player1" = 1L, "player2" = -1L)) %>% 
  spread(player, role, fill = 0L)

#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   game_id    aa    bb    cc
#>     <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1       1     1     0    -1
#> 2       2    -1     1     0
#> 3       3     0    -1     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pivot_longer()` to stack those columns starting with "player" and then pivot it to wide. The advantage is that you can do recoding within `pivot_wider()` by the argument `values_fn`.

```
library(tidyverse)

dat %>%
  rowid_to_column("id") %>%
  pivot_longer(starts_with("player")) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, names_sort = TRUE,
              values_from = name, values_fill = 0,
              values_fn = function(x) c(1, -1)[match(x, c("player1", "player2"))])

# # A tibble: 3 x 4
#      id    aa    bb    cc
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1     1     0    -1
# 2     2    -1     1     0
# 3     3     0    -1     1
```

***Note:*** *Development on `gather()`/`spread()` is complete, and for new code we recommend switching to `pivot_longer()`/`_wider()`, which is easier to use, more featureful, and still under active development.*

Comment: I would say that development is complete is a good thing. If pivot_* is still under development that same development might break existing code. That happened with gather()/spread() some years back.